# how add click lightbox to div img here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a [script](http://www.wklejto.pl/648153) to load an image to div after *onclick method*

I tried, but I could not insert javascript code here.

How add a href lightbox here? in to the img?

```
var str = "<img src='" + name + "' >";
document.getElementById("bigview").innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: set your code in fiddle and post link:https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c1ro7jyk/

Comment: see in F12 console your errors

Comment: everything works
the photo is loaded but wants to add a lightbox link to the img
I do not know how to write the code

Comment: lightbox you mean something like this??:https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l8vtg1

Comment: The function "enlarge()" is giving not defined all the time, even it's there. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your lightbox script uses the class 'lightbox', then you will have to modify your script and include an `<a>` link that contains that class. I repeat, this depends on the logic that your lightbox script uses (it can either add a class on the  tag or on the actual  tag).

You will have to replace this in your script:

`var str = "<img src='" + name + "' >";`

with this:

`var str = "<a href='" + name + "' class='lightbox'><img src='" + name + "' ></a>";`

I also assume you have an element in your HTML like this:

`<div id="bigview"></div>`